# How to use same custom domain for Web app hosted on Azure and web application hosted on window's IIS server?

Tags: azure, subdomain, appdomainsetup

I have a application which is hosted in IIS on window server and application URL is "www.hire.com/jobborad". Now i am going to add new feature(sub application) for example "Candidate Hub" so
I am planning to created separate code-base and host that application in Azure as Web App but i want to use the same parent domain of my original application. my sub application's URL will be a "www.hire.com/CandidateHub".

Is there any way that even if my application hosted in differently environment, I will be able to use same domain?If yes then could you please recommend me any tutorial, blog or any thing which help me to resolve my problem.

I search a lot on google but nothing find useful.

Thanks in-advance for help.

> Note : Mentioned URLs are just for example. Those are not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is usually done with the URL Rewrite Module in IIS.
Don't be surprised that the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) are quite old. They are still valid for latest Win Server and IIS.

for external routing you also may need the [ARR](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47333) feature which should be downloaded via the Web Platform Installer.

Comment: I checked the document but this is something different than my problem. I already have a website on IIS(Window server) with the domain name and now I have hosted a sub-module of the same site in Azure as a web app Service. Now I want to use the same parent domain for both sites in Azure as well as in IIS on Window Server.

Comment: this is exactly what URLRewrite can do. Serving `www.hire.com/jobborad` locally and routing `www.hire.com/CandidateHub` to Azure, which can be like `hire.azurewebsites.net/hub`and pretend to be locally. May be you also need ARR for this installed. I will edit the answer